# How to check if new scene is created in Xcode UI Testing?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

The app is a simple editor app and it supports multiple windows on iPad and Mac Catalyst.
A new window can be opened by New toolbar item or New menu on the Mac menubar.

I'm writing UI testing and not for sure how to check new scene is created.

```
func testNewEditor() throws {
        
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()
        
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    let menuBarsQuery = XCUIApplication().menuBars
    menuBarsQuery.menuBarItems["File"].click()
    menuBarsQuery.menuItems["new_editor"].click()
        
    // check new scene is created?
        
    #endif
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems working.

```
app.children(matching: .window).count
```